Chat FAQ section-specific links don't expand, essentially hiding information
Just now I was searching for official information on the criteria for chatrooms to be frozen or deleted, in order to help a user who was asking about it.
The auto-message notifying that a room has been frozen or deleted (example) links to https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#retention but that page looks like this:

Just two sentences, right? And then the rest of the FAQ below as promised.
Thing is ... there's actually more info than that, as quoted in this meta post for example:

Rooms will exist indefinitely, so long as there is at least one person actively talking in the room. ... Rooms not worth retaining which are inactive for 7 days will be deleted. Rooms worth retaining which are inactive for 14 days will be frozen.

Where are those sentences about deleted and frozen rooms? They don't appear in that yellow highlighted text above.
They are still in the chat FAQ, though. The only way to find them is to go to the full chat FAQ page, https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq not https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#retention, and then expand the section on "Will these rooms exist forever?" to get this:

But the second paragraph, and the images between the two paragraphs, are totally invisible when you go to https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#retention - there is no way to get that information from the section-specific link except by going to the full FAQ and then expanding the section.
A section-specific link that actually hides section-specific info seems wrong, so I'm reporting this as a bug.

Yup the anchors there are 100% broken.... for many years, like too many bugs on SE. :/
